# Proportional positioning of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, electron

I'm making my first electron app. I have the initial [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdQko.png). What I want is when user resizes window:

- Red part should change both width and height
- Blue part should change only height, but not width
- Green part should change only width, but not height

In .NET WinForms it would be a trivial task:

- set Red anchors to Left, Top, Right, Bottom
- set Blue anchors to Top, Right, Bottom
- and Green anchors to Left, Right, Bottom

How can I achieve the same effect with HTML + CSS?

I think I can use table element, but I've read that tables are discouraged to use in page layout.

Comment: You might want to take a look at flexbox layout :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: @MimiEAM, I'll look into it. Seems to be interesting. Just found a Holy Grail demo, almost exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```css
.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
.sub {
  margin-right:5px;
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.red {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="sub">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not expand to bottom, i.e. does not have bottom anchor. When dragging window up and down red and blue parts must be stretched alongside with window and green part must be always at the bottom.

Comment: Well, not actually fine :) I wanted that green and blue parts keep one of their sides always constant. So I have to replace percentage in `flex: 0 0 10%` in green selector to pixels and same for the blue part.

Comment: well finally you got what you were looking for. give em constant width and height as you did..